# Playing a System sound in tvos [swift]

Tags: swift, tvos

In iOS I can play a system sound with the following code:

```
// import this
import AVFoundation

// create a sound ID, in this case its the tweet sound.
let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1016

// to play sound
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (systemSoundID)
```

There is this link https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary to a list of available system sounds in iOS

My question is are system sounds available in tvOS? and which ones are available.

Answer (score 1):

SO I found the Answer. . .

The above code works fine on **an actual Apple TV**.  It does not work in the simulator. (It plays no system sounds in the Simulator.) Must be a bug.

I'm using Xcode version 7.3 and the 9.3 tvOS Simulator.

The above link to a list of sound files seems to work.  I've tried 5 different systems sounds that work.

Comment: Add a RADAR at apple #25831780

Answer (score 0):

If the sound doesn't play in the simulator but does play on a live Apple TV, it might be that you've disabled user interface sounds.

To enable, load the System Preferences, select Sounds, and then tick the `Play user interface sound effects` checkbox (and also increase the Alert volume)

When you play the system sound, it should play in the simulator now.